# Formating life-tables to use in survival analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to use the 'relsurv' package in R to compare the survival of a cohort to national life tables. The code below shows my problem using the example from relsurv but changing the life-table data. I've just used two years and two ages in the life-table data below, the actual data is much larger but gives the same error. The error is 'invalid ratetable argument' but I've formatted it as per the example life-tables 'slopop' and 'survexp.us'.

```
library(survival)
library(relsurv)
data(rdata) # example data from relsurv
raw = read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors = F, sep=' ', text='
Year Age sex qx
1980 30 1 0.00189
1980 31 1 0.00188
1981 30 1 0.00191
1981 31 1 0.00191
1980 30 2 0.00077
1980 31 2 0.00078
1981 30 2 0.00076
1981 31 2 0.00074
')

ages = c(30,40) # in years
years = c(1980, 1990)
rtab = array(data=NA, dim=c(length(ages), 2, length(years))) # set up blank array: ages, sexes, years
for (y in unique(raw$Year)){
  for (s in 1:2){
    rtab[ , s, y-min(years)+1] = -1 *  log(1-subset(raw, Year==y&sex==s)$qx) / 365.24 # probability of death in next year, transformed to hazard (see ratetables help)
  }
}
attributes(rtab)$dimnames[[1]] = as.character(ages)
attributes(rtab)$dimnames[[2]] = c('male','female')
attributes(rtab)$dimnames[[3]] = as.character(years)
attributes(rtab)$dimid <- c("age", "sex", 'year')
attributes(rtab)$dim <- c(length(ages), 2, length(years))
attributes(rtab)$factor = c(0,0,1)
attributes(rtab)$type = c(2,1,4)
attributes(rtab)$cutpoints[[1]] = ages*365.24 # must be in days
attributes(rtab)$cutpoints[[2]] = NULL
attributes(rtab)$cutpoints[[3]] = as.date(paste("1Jan", years, sep='')) # must be date
attributes(rtab)$class = "ratetable"

# example from relsurv
rsmul(Surv(time,cens) ~ sex+as.factor(agegr)+
        ratetable(age=age*365.24, sex=sex, year=year),
      data=rdata, ratetable=rtab, int=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the transrate function from the relsurv package to reformat the data. That should give you a compatible dataset.

Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Three things to add:

1. You should set `attributes(rtab)$factor = c(0,1,0)`, since sex (the second dimension) is a factor (i.e., doesn't change over time).
2. A good way to check whether something is a valid rate table is to use the `is.ratetable()` function. `is.ratetable(rtab, verbose = TRUE)` will even return a message stating what was wrong.
3. Check the result of `is.ratetable` without using `verbose` *first*, because it will *lie* about valid rate tables.

The rest of this comment is about this lie.

If the `type` attribute isn't given, `is.ratetable` will calculate it using the `factor` attribute; you can see this by just printing the function. However, it seems to do so incorrectly. It uses `type <- 1 * (fac == 1) + 2 * (fac == 0) + 4 * (fac > 0)`, where `fac` is `attributes(rtab)$factor`.

But the next section, which checks the `type` attribute if it's provided, says the only valid values are `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.  It's impossible to get `1` from the code above.

For example, let's examine the `slopop` ratetable provided with the `relsurv` package.

```
library(relsurv)
data(slopop)
is.ratetable(slopop)
# [1] TRUE

is.ratetable(slopop, verbose = TRUE)
# [1] "wrong length for cutpoints 3"
```

I think this is where your rate table is being hung up.